# NFS Configuration: 2 slaves and 1 master

Tags: nfs, nfsclient

how are you?

I'm setting up a NFS server to handle file sync between 2 slaves, but I can't find a configuration file that handles this kind of structure.

My desired outcome is:

- 1 master (nfs server) (this is the only machine with write access).
- 2 slaves (web servers) (files will be put here from master server only)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out:

On the master server, I specify the following config:

```
/NFS slave1_ipaddr(ro,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) slave2_addr(ro,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

On each of the slaves, I mount the folder:

```
mount -t nfs master_ipaddr:/NFS /usr/share/nginx/html/docroot
```